# Html interpretation for different browsers

Tags: html, browser

Recently, I downloaded a JQuery plugin for animation on tabbed content of a html page. The html defined for Tabs and their respective contents and animation is obtained by the 
JQuery. here is a sample html of my tabs.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#two">PED</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Five">SPDE</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#one">SDE</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="box-wrapper">
  <div id="Seven" class="content-box">
    <div class="col-one col">
      <a href="" target="_blank"
         title="Click to go to Advanced-Design Team Site">
        <img src=""/>
      </a>
    </div>
  <div class="col-two col">
  <h3>
    <a href="" target="_blank"
       style="color: Black; text-decoration: underline"
       title="Click to go to Advanced-Design Team Site">
         Advanced Design
    </a>
  </h3>
  <p>Welcome to Advanced Design Group.</p>
</div>
```

There are remaining divs as coded above.

I displayed this tabbed html page in another page using an iframe tag.When I click on any one of the tabs the page auto snaps to the starting of the content page. This doesn't happen in Firefox, but it displays the content as expected without snapping. In IE and Chrome, the page snaps to the starting of the respective tab. We need to re scroll to the top of the page.

Not sure why this happens, Is there any issue in the way browsers interpret the HTML or my HTML code is wrong? I don't see any other way except to use the
 approach. I know this is causing the issue but is there any way out to make the page not snap in IE or chrome or do I need to develop my page with tabbed content without using the approach I did now. this is kind of Road end for me. Dont know where to go.

Any pointers would be of great help.
Thanks,

Comment: Is there a reason you are using iFrames? And do I understand you correct, you want to scroll to the top of the parent page whenever a tab is clicked inside the iFrame?

Comment: post a link with your page to a better help

Comment: Also, what jQuery plugin are you using? Can you approximate a jsFiddle?

Comment: Hi all,I am doing this in SharePoint and displaying the page in Page viewer web part. it uses basically Iframe. The jquery plugin(named slot machines tab) which I donwloaded form css tricks site at the URL(http://css-tricks.com/slot-machine-tabs/). I just formatted the divs as per my requirement and embedded it in a html page and displayed it by SharePoint Page viewer web part

Comment: Also, from your experience, can anyone let me know, if there is any other way to develop tabs without using <a href="#id"> format?

Comment: Here is a fiddle that you can see the tabs.http://jsfiddle.net/rQTpB/4/ But if we display the same page in an iframe on a different page with lot of scrolling, on clicking any of the tabs, will snap to the starting of the content for that respective div except in Mozilla. AmI clear on my problem now? kindly let me know